# How to fix ngnix.conf for redirect from .html and index.html

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to do redirect from urls, real page exist here - mysite.com/folder/index.html :

1. mysite.com/folder/index.html to mysite.com/folder/
2. mysite.com/folder.html to mysite.com/folder/
3. mysite.com/index.html to mysite.com

This is part of my config

```
server_name k.my.net www.k.my.net;

index index.html;
root /var/www/demo/k.my.net/current/public;

rewrite ^(.*/)index\.html$ $1;
rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $1/;

location / {   
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Also try do it with:

```
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
  }

 location ~ \.html$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
 }

 location @htmlext {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html permanent;
 }
```

3-rd solution ERROR_LOOP

```
    location ~* ^/([a-zA-Z1-9_-]*/)index\.html$ {
      return 301 $1;
    }
    location ~* ^/([a-zA-Z1-9_-]*/?[1-9a-zA-Z_-]*)\.html$ {
     return 301 /$1/;
    }

   location ~* ^/([a-zA-Z1-9_-]*/?[a-zA-Z1-9_-]*)/$ {
     try_files /$1.html /$1/index.html =404;    
    }
```

Comment: You might benefit redirecting just `mysite.com/folder.html to mysite.com/folder/`. For the other two, just make index.html the default page in a folder.

Comment: @zedfoxus, can i do it for each folder like this? location ~ (.+/) { index index.html}

Comment: Oh yeah, see `index index.php index.html;` line in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/change-default-web-root-for-nginx-on-one-click-install-lemp-14-04. You can use `index index.html` in your `server` config. If you wanted to specify different index files in different folders, you can do that too. See `https://serverfault.com/questions/596936/nginx-specify-different-index-file-name-for-subdirectory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression `location` to extract the part of the URI before the trailing `/` and use `try_files` to test the two alternatives. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ ^(.*)/$ {
    try_files $1/index.html $1.html =404;
}
```

The `location` also matches `/` which will satisfy your third requirement.

---

Your `rewrite` statements should be safe, but if they cause redirection loops, you may need to replace them with an `if` block and test the original request in `$request_uri`. For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^([^?]*?)(/index|)(\.html)(\?.*)?$) {
    return 301 $1/$4;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. First part helps me to solve my problem.